# Cannot properly test ErrorController Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

due to this tutorial - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page I wanted to customize my error page ie. when someone go to `www.myweb.com/blablablalb3` I want to return page with text "wrong url request".
All works fine:

```
@Controller
public class ApiServerErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "error";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "forward:/error-page.html";
    }
}
```

But I dont know how to test it:

```
@Test
    public void makeRandomRequest__shouldReturnErrorPage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get(RANDOM_URL))
                .andDo(print());

    }
```

print() returns:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {X-Application-Context=[application:integration:-1]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

So I cant created something like this:

```
.andExpect(forwardedUrl("error-page"));
```

because it fails, but on manual tests error-page is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing of a custom `ErrorController` with `MockMvc` is unfortunately not supported.

For a detailed explanation, see the official recommendation from the Spring Boot team ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5574#issuecomment-419481530)).

> To be sure that any error handling is working fully, it's necessary to
>   involve the servlet container in that testing as it's responsible for
>   error page registration etc. Even if MockMvc itself or a Boot
>   enhancement to MockMvc allowed forwarding to an error page, you'd be
>   testing the testing infrastructure not the real-world scenario that
>   you're actually interested in.
>
> Our recommendation for tests that want to be sure that error handling
>   is working correctly, is to use an embedded container and test with
>   WebTestClient, RestAssured, or TestRestTemplate.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to use [@ControllerAdvice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes)

In this way you can work around the problem and you can continue to use MockMvc with the big advantage that you are not required to have a running server.

Of course to test explicitly the error page management you need a running server. My suggestion is mainly for those who implemented ErrorController but still want to use MockMvc for unit testing.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler(FileSizeLimitExceededException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Throwable> handleFileException(HttpServletRequest request, FileSizeLimitExceededException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(ex, HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Throwable> handleUnexpected(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable throwable) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(throwable, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }

}
```